# Trimming characters of a command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am running command in a bash shell as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=TEST.DOMAIN --username=Administrator --password=mypassword
```

Although I would like to trim the last 6 characters from the end of the line (before processing) - but I would like to be able to do this within the shell and not rely on a script

Comment: Strange question, doesn't make any sense to me. Characters are deleted from the end of line by pressing backspace six times. Do you want a readline key binding which does this?

Comment: @Hauke Laging Well the command is being executed by a program, but the password being input into the command is too long and hence needs to be trimmed

Comment: Now it does not make sense to me either :/

Comment: How does the command get into the shell?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What is it you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function:

```
foo (){
  /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --request-nt-key --domain=TEST.DOMAIN --username=Administrator --password="${1%??????}"
}
```

Call it:

```
foo m7s5p3rs3cr3tpXss
```

Of course input sanitizing (not shown here) applies.

Comment: How exactly does this trim the last six characters from the password?

Comment: @MadHatter I made an edit to correct that.

Comment: @MadHatter You are right. I'm not answering the question, but rather trying to _guess_ what is being asked. I'm removing this answer.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Indeed, that should do it, but I'm not sure anymore about the way the OP wants this to happen :|